# Is the Ramban's observation of "images of young dog pups in urine" recorded by anyone else?

Tags: sources-mekorot, science, chukas, ramban

The [Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Numbers.21.9?lang=bi) notes in his commentary on [Bamidbar 21:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.21.9?lang=bi&aliyot=1) the following:

(*Source from [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/)*)

> וכבר הזכירו דבר מנוסה מפלאות התולדה כי נשוך הכלב השוטה אחרי שנשתטה בחליו אם יקובל השתן שלו בכלי זכוכית יראה בשתן דמות גורי כלבים קטנים ואם תעביר המים במטלית ותסננם לא תמצא בהם שום רושם כלל וכשתחזירם לכלי הזכוכית וישתהו שם כשעה תחזור ותראה שם גורי הכלבים מתוארים
>
> *It has already been mentioned and a tested matter from the wonders of science, that one who is bit by a rabid dog, after he has been affected by the [rabies] disease, if a sample of his urine is placed in a glass vessel, small, young dog pups will be observed in the urine. If you were to strain the urine through a cloth, no marks will be seen in the urine. [However,] when you return it [the urine] into a glass vessel and let it sit for about an hour, the image of the young dog pups will appear [in the urine]*

## My Question

In a similar vein to what I asked in [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91691/is-the-rambans-observation-of-red-drops-similar-to-blood-developing-on-a-mirro#91691), Where else besides for the Ramban is this phenomenon recorded? Is there any other recounting of such an occurrence?

(*I am impartial about the sources, be that Jewish or Non-Jewish*)

Comment: see the way it is described [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=SL34EWxAJfYC&pg=PA257&lpg=PA257&dq=dog+bite+image+urine+-pet&source=bl&ots=0A4YwIHWpx&sig=ryRyH63d-8mQ4DcUE7GSYbTjiOw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE1ubI94DcAhUK4YMKHaz9AoIQ6AEIhAEwEQ#v=onepage&q=dog%20bite%20image%20urine%20-pet&f=false), it sounds like a part of the insanity, but no source, though.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות theres this too https://books.google.ca/books?id=Au51AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA128&dq=images+dog+pups+urine+rabies&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNxrXf-IDcAhUV24MKHWhuBbEQ6AEITDAH#v=onepage&q=images%20dog%20pups%20urine%20rabies&f=false

Comment: @רבותמחשבות but the sources are later than the Ramban.

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi Are you only looking for sources pre-dating Ramnban?

Comment: @Alex ideally yes.

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi Perhaps edit that into the question.

Answer (score 5):

Saul Lieberman, with his unique erudition and knowledge of Greco-Roman literature, writes as follows (Hellenism In Jewish Palestine p. 190):

> Nahmanides and Rabbenu Bahya in their commentaries on Num. 21:9 refer to our text in TB [Yoma 84a] and remark that this is also recorded in the "medical books." I was not able to find any reference to it in the *early* (my emphasis) Greek and Latin medical works.
>
> The first physician who mentions it is Paulus Aegineta (beg. 7th c.) who informs us that "it is thought that the bitten man sees in the water the image of the dog who inflicted the bite." From Paulus it was taken over in later medical literature. However, Paulus Silentiarius (6th c.) already refers to this belief in an amatory epigram: "They say that a man bitten by a mad dog sees the brute's image in the water." The rabbinic text which credits Abaye with the advice to a man bitten by a mad dog that he drink water from a tube in order to avoid the image of the dog seems to be the earliest instance on record of the previously cited belief.

Comment: My question is regarding seeing images of puppies in a infected persons urine. This relates to earlier in the Ramban

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi Hence my crediting of Leiberman's erudition. The above is probably as good as it gets. (I'd wager that specific depiction isn't recorded elsewhere; could be mere effective imagery of the other recorded references.)

Answer (score 1):

The Rabbainu Be'chay במדבר כא/ט writes that this is referred to in the Gemorah יומא פד.

דנכית ליה ... תריסר ירחי שתא כי שתי מיא לא לישתי אלא בגובתא דנחשא דילמא חזי בבואה דשידא וליסתכן

The Gemara continues to discuss the baraita: One bitten by a mad dog will die. ... And during those twelve months of the year, [when his clothes are buried,] when he drinks water, let him drink only from a copper tube and not from a spring, lest he see the image of the demon in the water and be endangered.

Comment: Ramban himself cites that *gemara*. Don't see what RB is adding.

Comment: @Oliver - You"re right. However, the Ramban just says which Daf, while the RB quotes the actual Gemorah.

Comment: @Oliver, there was no such citation in the question above, so this is a great answer to a terribly asked question.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question, this relates to the part of of the Ramban I did not quote

Comment: @msh210 if you mind explaining whats so terrible that would be great.

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi you ask for other sources but you know of one quoted in the _Ramban_ himself and concealed that info from us.

Comment: @msh210 The gemara doesn't present the same hydrophobic reaction which Ramban depicts. I understand OP to be asking for a source for "וידוע מדרכי הרפואות שכל נשוכי בעלי הארס... כמו **שכתוב בספרי** **הרפואות**"; Ramban clearly did not glean his description from that gemara. (*This* may be the most "horrible" part of the q: not specifying so.)

Comment: @msh210 I believe you didn't learn the Ramban then. Please reread my question.